# How can I make a web application to access local files?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, web-applications, local-storage

I am creating a web application which needs to access the local audio and video files in the client's system.

The basic idea is, when the site is opened in the browser it must have access to the files of the client system and must display all the media files in a requested directory.

Can this be implemented using any concepts of JavaScript, Java, Perl, Ajax or any other client-side languages?

Some questions have solution to this but now it has become obsolete  so is there any new way